# how to set typescript member variables that are unknown in constructor

Tags: typescript, declaration, member, union-types

I am learning Typescript and want to know how to define class member variables properly.

At the moment, I am declaring them in the class, above the constructor, but in order to make sure that they are instantiated in the constructor (or I get a warning), I declare them as whatever type | null.
This means that if I can then instantiate the member variable in the constructor by setting equal to null, and then setting to its proper value, when I am able.

I don't know that this is a correct method to declare member variables.
As an example :

```
export default class FlowerBed {
  canv:HTMLCanvasElement | null;
  ctx:CanvasRenderingContext2D | null;
  p2d:Path2D;
  t:number;
  currentPoint:Array<number>;
  to:number = 0;
  image:HTMLImageElement | null;
  imagesrc:CanvasImageSource | null;
  pattern:CanvasPattern | null;

  constructor (garden:HTMLCanvasElement) {
    this.image = null;
    this.imagesrc = null;
    this.canv = null;
    this.ctx = null;
    this.pattern = null;
    this.to = 0;
    this.p2d = new Path2D();
    this.t = 0;
    this.currentPoint = [160,350];  
  }
```

I don't have the value of canvas,ctx, pattern etc at the time of construction.

Is there a more correct way of proceeding?

Many thanks...

Comment: Do you use `null` with a special meaning? I mean is there any difference to your code if you replace these `null`s with `undefined`?

Comment: So I would have ```image:HTMLImageElement | undefined```  
and this.image = undefined in the constructor?
Undefined is a better option than null I guess, it makes more sense semantically.

Comment: However, many React components expose their variables as unions with null, which I have to adhere to in parameter definitions...

Comment: React do use `null` with a special meaning, for example, you have to return `null` as a rendering result otherwise it is considered as an error. It is a way of making things less error prone that may be excessive if you use other tools such as TypeScript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if you don't need to use `null` with special meaning you can simplify your class

```
export default class FlowerBed {
  canv?: HTMLCanvasElement;
  ctx?: CanvasRenderingContext2D;
  p2d: Path2D = new Path2D();
  t: number = 0;
  currentPoint: Array<number> = [160, 350];
  to: number = 0;
  image?: HTMLImageElement;
  imagesrc?: CanvasImageSource;
  pattern?: CanvasPattern;

  constructor(garden: HTMLCanvasElement) {
    // ...
  }

  someMethod() {
    // Note the exclamation mark – it tells ts you are sure the property has a value
    return this.canv!.getBoundingClientRect();
  }
}
```

`?` after field name means that the field can be missing what is almost the same as having it `undefined`. Depending on your experience you may prefer to put value assignments to the constructor, but you still can avoid null assignments here.

It's worth noting that uninitialized properties do not present in the object, so runtime checks such as `hasOwnProperty` return `false`.

```
const fb = new FlowerBed(canvasEl);
fb.hasOwnProperty('ctx'); // false
```

So if it is important you may initialize them but not necesseraly to do in in constructor.

```
export default class FlowerBed {
  canv?: HTMLCanvasElement;
  ctx?: CanvasRenderingContext2D = undefined;
  // ...
}
```

It may be useful when there is a case when the property may get some nullish value in runtime and that is one of the reasons some developers distinguish `undefined` and `null` values, using `undefined` as "not yet initialized" and `null` as "empty or non-existent value"

Comment: I have to initialise unknown variables to undefined in the constructor, in order to use the this keyword, but that is fine.  Many thanks.

Comment: @millerthegorilla: If you know for certain that it is going to be initialized before being referenced, you can replace the `?` with a `!` to signal to the compiler that the undefined status is only temporary and you know what you're doing, thus preserving type strictness while permitting delayed initialization.